# Is putting computation intensive job into kernel a bad idea for node.js?

Tags: node.js

Node.js is quite good for io intensive jobs. But for computation intensive job, it is not so good.

I know that there are many ways to pipe data to another process as a solution. Or, alternatively, implement a native module to do the calculation asynchronously in another thread. However, this requires a understanding of v8, libuv and node.js internals. Also, all of them may be changed for evolution.

Since Nodejs is all about asynchronous i/o, converting all computation intensive jobs into i/o operation is a reasonable idea. A computation intensive job could be done by a kernel module, accessed through file i/o interface. For example, creating a file in a special file system, open the file and write all data, then read back the result.

I understand that there are security problems. But from the viewpoint of the performance and portability, it is a bad idea? any pitfalls?

Comment: I see no reason to put this into the kernel.  Just create one or more worker processes (often called a work queue) and use standard interprocess communication (probably just a socket of some kind) to send them jobs and get results.  There's really no reason to go modifying a kernel to get multiple processes involved in running CPU intensive stuff.  In a few dozen lines of code or so, you can create a worker process that accepts jobs via an http request or via a webSocket message.  Do the work and notify back the result.

Comment: So, Yes I'd say it's a bad idea to put this kind of stuff into the kernel.  There is no reason for it to be in the kernel.  This is app-specific code that belongs in the app-space.  You can freely communicate with it via TCP.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is a piece of software that makes your computer usable. It offers services like the separation of processes, resource management, hardware interfaces and others. This with a comparatively low overhead.

Extending the kernel to do heavy computations will effectively make your computer unusable. There will be no way to interrupt the heavy computation, hence every other process will have to wait for it to finish.

Apart from that the kernel programming environment doesn't offer the usual interface you are used to. So if you are worried about having to understand v8, libuv and node.js internals, don't even think of kernel programming.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to put this into the kernel. Just create one or more worker processes (often called a work queue) and use standard interprocess communication (probably just a socket of some kind) to send them jobs and get results. There's really no reason to go modifying a kernel to get multiple processes involved in running CPU intensive stuff. In a few dozen lines of code or so, you can create a worker process that accepts jobs via an http request or via a webSocket message. Do the work and notify back the result.

> But from the viewpoint of the performance and portability, it is a bad idea?

So, Yes I'd say it's a bad idea to put this kind of stuff into the kernel. There is no reason for it to be in the kernel. This is app-specific code that belongs in the app-space. You can freely communicate with it via TCP.  Putting it in the kernel would not be portable at all.  If your CPU-intensive processes were written in any cross platform language/library (such as node.js itself) then they could be very portable.

> Since Nodejs is all about asynchronous i/o, converting all computation intensive jobs into i/o operation is a reasonable idea.

It's a reasonable idea to move CPU-intensive work out of the main node.js process that runs your server and into some other process or set of processes.  That allows the main node.js process to deal with it asynchronously.  You don't have to give it a file I/O in order to deal with it asynchronously.  Just communicating with these other processes via any typical interprocess communication (such as any form of networking) will work just fine and is likely less complicated than building a custom file system.

> A computation intensive job could be done by a kernel module, accessed through file i/o interface. For example, creating a file in a special file system, open the file and write all data, then read back the result.

You don't have to put the work into the kernel and you don't have to interface with it via a special file system to get all the advantages you want.  Just put it in a set of app-level worker processes and communicate with them via TCP networking.  No need for kernel mods to do this.  More robust, much faster to code, more portable, etc...

> Or, alternatively, implement a native module to do the calculation asynchronously in another thread.

Again, there is likely no reason to do this CPU-intensive coding in a native module.  Just do it in another process that you start when needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an detailed and extensive answer. What is the recommended IPC? Unix Domain Sockets moves a lot of data from buffer to buffer which does not sound like a good choice for massive data processing. I googled and found kdbus which advertises a one/zero copy feature. Have you any experience on that and similar thing and can give me some advices?

Comment: @matianfu - There are lots of choices for IPC.  Which to use depends a lot on the specific situation and requirements and what you are most trying to optimize for.  If you want help with that question, I'd suggest you create a new question, describe your situation in detail, what platform you are targeting, describe your priorities and what you most want to optimize for and ask in that new question.